# Join tables mysql with two different keys

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I need to join same tables with different keys,

I am using codeigniter, so below is syntax for joining it,

```
    $this->db->join('sc_countries', 'sc_countries.country_id = sc_users.user_country', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('sc_countries', 'sc_countries.country_id = sc_agents.agent_country', 'LEFT');
```

When i tried to join this way, it throw with error

```
Not unique table/alias: 'sc_countries'
```

How can i do this type of join?

Thanks in advnace,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL interpreter is not finding the exact table as same table is joined two times.

It is conflicting. To avoid conflict, rename tables by usin alias:

```
$this->db->join('sc_countries AS C', 'C.country_id = sc_users.user_country', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('sc_countries AS D', 'D.country_id = sc_agents.agent_country', 'LEFT');
```